# How to determine date selected from UIDatePicker after dismissing popover?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uidatepicker, uistoryboard

I currently have a popover `DatePickerViewController` that I created in storyboard which has a UIDatePicker. I want to be able to dismiss the popover and send the date to my original view `ViewController` but I'm not sure how to do this. I know how to obtain the date from the UIDatePicker, I just don't know how to obtain that data when the popover is dismissed.

I am trying this in `ViewController` but the NSLog output is never displayed...

```
- (void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    NSDate *selectedDate = ((DatePickerViewController *) popoverController.contentViewController).datePicker.date;
    NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:selectedDate];
    int selectedYear = [dateComponents year];
    int selectedMonth = [dateComponents month];
    int selectedDay = [dateComponents day];

    self.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d/%d",selectedMonth,selectedDay,selectedYear];

    NSLog(@"hello world"); // never shows up
}
```

Comment: I have `ViewController` set as `UIPopoverControllerDelegate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set delegate=self in prepareForSegue:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDatePicker"]) {
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue;
    popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;

    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
    popoverController.delegate=self;
}
}
```